# Why Interrupt handler entry code check Carry flag?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt

I am trying to generate an interrupt in a VM and have written a simple interrupt handler but when I try to test this interrupt generation and handling, kernel crashes because of page fault. Now I debugged the issue and found out that in 'entry_64.S' file where 'error_entry' is called to push registers onto stack and check for GS there following code:

```
    xorl %ebx,%ebx
    testl $3,CS+8(%rsp)
    je error_kernelspace
 error_swapgs:
    SWAPGS
```

When interrupt is handled, CPU will push EFLAGS to (rsp)+CS+8 location. So in above code 'testl' instruction check if flag's Carry flag was set at the time of interrupt to detect if interrupt was in kernel mode or in user mode.

Can please someone explain why Carry flag is checked here?

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer on the Linux kernel mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think it's checking whether CS corresponds to a kernel thread, see the comment for a similar construct at [`ret_from_fork`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S?v=2.6.39#L412).

Comment: After too much digging I found that there is a very thin line between generating an interrupt and exception as they can be interchanged by just one flag. The issue was not in kernel, it was the way I generated the interrupt.